# Removing default ggplot legend and create a customized one

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, legend

I want to use `ggplot` to plot a barplot. When I define all parameters, ggplot will automatically add legend based on dataframe column names. here is my dataframe:

```
         shift  Var      Ave
        <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
1           0 Ave_los    268
2           0 Ave_los_n  195
3           1 Ave_los    284
4           1 Ave_los_n  217
5           2 Ave_los    214
6           2 Ave_los_n  194
```

and here is the code I am using to plot:

```
ggplot(data=data3, aes(x=shift, y=Ave, fill=Var)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0:2)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=round(Ave,digit=2)), vjust=1.6, color="black", position = position_dodge(0.9), size=2.3)
```

The result of this plot is shown below:

[image: created plot]

However, I don't want to use **Ave_los** and **Ave_los_n** as the legend and instead, I want to replace them with **Average time (positive group)** and **Average time (negative group)**. how can I do this?

Comment: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/

Comment: @astrofunkswag Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the values of the column "Var" using recode in tidyverse. A whole explanation on this given [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/recode.html)

```
library(tidyverse)
    data3%>%recode(Ave, Ave_los = "Average Time (positive group)", Ave_los_n = "Average Time (negative group")%>%ggplot(data=data3, aes(x=shift, y=Ave, fill=Var))+geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+ scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0:2)) +  geom_text(aes(label=round(Ave,digit=2)), vjust=1.6, color="black", position = position_dodge(0.9), size=2.3)
```